# Pass data from std::vector to uniform array in glsl

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have a uniform in a shader like this:

```
uniform vec3 origins[10];
```

and a std::vector in my code like this:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> origins;
```

that is filled with ten `glm::vec3` elements.

Does anyone know how do I pass that to the shader? I thought:

```
GLint originsLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "origins");
glUniform3fv(originsLoc, 10, origins.data());
```

would do it, but it wont compile. The error says there is `no matching function for call to 'glUniform3fv'`. How do I pass the data in the `std::vector` in a way that satisfies the `glUniform3fv` function?

Comment: "it doesnt work"...crash?  Nothing drawn?  Something unexpected drawn?

Comment: It wont compile. Should the code posted compile? The error says there is `no matching function for call to 'glUniform3fv'`. I edited the question with this info.

Comment: You should have to cast the pointer to a `const GLfloat*`. Without the cast, the function signature doesn't match. You should also include the **full* compiler output. I'm guessing the actual error includes extra type/signature information that you have omitted, unfortunately.

Comment: Which version of OpenGL & GLSL are you using? Then if you are using versions 3.2+ then are you using the Core Profile Specification or the Compatibility Profile Specification?

Comment: What OS are you using and what IDE - Compiler are you using?

Comment: Start with [`origins.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), or: `&origins[0]` (C++03). However, you have to ensure that the uniform [layout](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_%28GLSL%29#Memory_layout) matches that of the contiguous vector data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a GLfloat and note a glm::vec3.
but here it is a any way:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
 GLint originsLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "origins[i]");
 glUniform3f(originsLoc, origins[i].x, origins[i].y, origins[i].z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, that, and @Cornstalks pointed me in the right direction. What I ended up doing is this, which also works: `glUniform3fv(originsLoc, origins.size(), reinterpret_cast<GLfloat *>(trackObstacle->obstaclesPopupNormals.data()))`